# Почему не отображается изображение после наложение на canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

есть код

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"), 
                context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                 
            var img = new Image();
   var imgT = new Image();
   
            img.src = "https://img.rosbalt.ru/photobank/1/c/a/0/Z8X2VMCx.jpg";
   imgT.src = "http://zabavnik.club/wp-content/uploads/background_html_1_16082041.jpg"
            img.onload = function() {
                 
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage(imgT, 300, 400,200,200);
    
            };
   console.log("url-final-  "+canvas.toDataURL());
```

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"
            style="background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc;">
            
        </canvas>
```

**На выводе в console.log выводится все что есть в Canvas в base64 img, при конвертация в png получается голое фото 1000x1000, но по идей должно быть две фото (одна поверх другой) почему их нету в финалином результате?**

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы ждете загрузки только одного изображения. Второе не успевает еще загрузиться.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var timer;
var loaded = [];
var img = new Image();
var imgT = new Image();

img.src = "https://img.rosbalt.ru/photobank/1/c/a/0/Z8X2VMCx.jpg";
imgT.src = "http://zabavnik.club/wp-content/uploads/background_html_1_16082041.jpg"

img.onload = loaded.push('img');
imgT.onload = loaded.push('imgT');

timer = setInterval(function(){
  if ( loaded.length == 2 ) {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage(imgT, 300, 400, 200, 200);
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 300);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=1000 height=1000></canvas>
```